# What kind of action will cause Blobcache on web.config back to false?

Tags: blob-cache

On our development SP2013 farm, I have enabled Blobcache according to [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770229(v=office.15).aspx#BLOB).

I simply changed the  line to enabled=true and create a folder c:\Blobcache.

After some days, I found there is nothing in c:\Blobcache and when I check back web.config, the line of BlobCache have been changed back to default. The Enabled attirube become "False" as default.

What kind of action will cause the change? Do I missed some setup to make attribute fixed? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you uninstall a solution in the meanwhile?

There is some kind of web.config versioning going on in SharePoint when you install and uninstall a new SharePoint solution package.

Comment: Yes! I was debug some solution using visual studio 2013. So Visual Studio disable the Blobcache for me? If so it should be a bug.

Comment: Not really a bug. If you uninstall a rollback logic will take place. Since you edited the current web.config file directly, the rollback will (incorrectly) conclude that the change in blobcache was a change done together with the installation of the latest solution. When uninstalling the latest solution the change in the blobcache setting will also be rolled back to the previous state.